# Strange values from vDSP_meanD

Tags: swift, accelerate-framework, vdsp

I am using the vDSP_meanD function to determine the average of a data set (consecutive diferences from an array)

The code I am using is below

```
func F(dataAllFrames:[Double],std:Double,medida:String)->Double{
    let nframes=dataAllFrames.count
    var diferencas_consecutivas_media = [Double](count: dataAllFrames.count-1, repeatedValue:0.0)
    var mediaDifConseq:Double = 0

    for(var i:Int=1; i<dataAllFrames.count; i++){
        diferencas_consecutivas_media[i-1]=dataAllFrames[i]-dataAllFrames[i-1]
    }

    var meanConseqDif = [Double](count: 1, repeatedValue:0.0)
    var meanConseqDifPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>(meanConseqDif)

    vDSP_meanvD(diferencas_consecutivas_media,1,meanConseqDifPtr,UInt(nframes))

    print( meanConseqDif[0])
}
```

The function F is called within a thread block

```
let group = dispatch_group_create()
let queue = dispatch_queue_create("myqueue.data.processor", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)
dispatch_group_async(group, queue) {
    F(measureData,std: std, medida: medida)
}
```

The F function is called in multiple dispatch block with different variables instances every now and then i get different values for the value returned from vDSP_meanD is there any context where this may happen ?
May the thread call have some influence on that?
Any "lights" would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect this code to work. This shouldn't be correct:

```
var meanConseqDif = [Double](count: 1, repeatedValue:0.0)
var meanConseqDifPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>(meanConseqDif)

vDSP_meanvD(diferencas_consecutivas_media,1,meanConseqDifPtr,UInt(nframes))
```

I believe this is pointing directly at the Array struct, so you're probably blowing away the metadata rather than updating the value you meant. But I would expect that you don't get the right answers at all in that case. Have you validated that your results are correct usually?

I think the code you mean is like this:

```
func F(dataAllFrames: [Double], std: Double, medida: String) -> Double {
    let nframes = UInt(dataAllFrames.count)
    var diferencas_consecutivas_media = [Double](count: dataAllFrames.count-1, repeatedValue:0.0)

    for(var i = 1; i < dataAllFrames.count; i += 1) {
        diferencas_consecutivas_media[i-1] = dataAllFrames[i] - dataAllFrames[i-1]
    }

    var mediaDifConseq = 0.0
    vDSP_meanvD(diferencas_consecutivas_media, 1, &mediaDifConseq, nframes)

    return mediaDifConseq
}
```

You don't need an output array to collect a single result. You can just use a Double directly, and use `&` to take an unsafe pointer to it.

Unrelated point, but you can get rid of all of the difference-generating code with a single zip and map:

```
let diferencasConsecutivasMedia = zip(dataAllFrames, dataAllFrames.dropFirst())
    .map { $1 - $0 }
```

I haven't profiled these two approaches, though. It's possible that your approach is faster. I find the zip and map much clearer and less error-prone, but others may feel differently.